# Make form inputs float correctly

Tags: html, css, forms, input, sass

I have this form:

[image: screenshot form image]

I want the last name input to be on the same line as the first name. I used float-left for both of them but it doesn't work.

```css
.first-name {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.last-name {
  float: left;
}

input,
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <section>
    <div class="first-name">
      <label for="first-name">First name</label>
      <input type="text" id="first-name" required> </div>
    <div class="last-name">
      <label for="last-name">Last name </label>
      <input type="text" id="last-name" required></div>

    <br style="clear:both;" />
  </section>
  <section>
    <label for="company">Company </label>
    <input type="text" id="company" required>

    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" required>
  </section>
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="REGISTER">
</form>
```

Comment: you have to put form inside the table tag.

Comment: you need to add 50% width in both divs .first-name & .last-name

Comment: @MinalChauhan i did it now and it doesnt work

Comment: Can you add full code? may be parent width will be effected.

Comment: We are in 2019, please don't use `<table>` to format your page. For example, Flexbox could be a good way to solve your problem. => https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Please check your scss selectors, it should work as expected but I would recommend using flexbox for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox to solve this.

```css
section.justify-content-btw {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

input,
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <section class="justify-content-btw">
    <div class="first-name">
      <label for="first-name">First name</label>
      <input type="text" id="first-name" required> </div>
    <div class="last-name">
      <label for="last-name">Last name </label>
      <input type="text" id="last-name" required></div>

    <br style="clear:both;" />
  </section>
  <section>
    <label for="company">Company </label>
    <input type="text" id="company" required>

    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" required>
  </section>
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="REGISTER">
</form>
```